# Set theory: Why are these two sets different?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working through a set theory book and one of the exercises is to explain why $\{z|z\subseteq \{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\{x|x\in \mathbb{Z}, 0<x<1\}$ are different.

I'm just completely stuck on this. For a start, I don't see why they are different: Aren't they both just equal to $\emptyset$?

Unrelated: Can anyone recommended me a good set theory book for beginners? (EDIT: Sorry, to be more clear, I'm not really enjoying the assigned text.) I've been recommended things like http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Sets.html?id=liado7rErEsC&redir_esc=y and http://www.lib.hku.hk/Press/9622090133.pdf - are these any good?

Thanks!

EDIT: It would really help if you explained why you downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should ask separate questions as new questions (elementary set theory book recommendations are bound to be duplicate, though).

Comment: @user92570 Before you ask, see if any of [these questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+elementary-set-theory) suits you.

Comment: To downvote a question like this is, imo, preposterous: the OP's asking a good question, he's showing some effort, and his "second" question is on set theory, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. The first set consists of all subsets of $\{\emptyset\}$. That would be $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$. The second set is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @user92570 $\emptyset = \{\}$ by definition, yes. As for the first: No. The subsets of $\{5\}$ are $\emptyset$ and $\{5\}$. $5$ is an _element_ of $\{5\}$.

Comment: @user92570 Nope, you should re-read the concepts of sets. $\{5\} \cup \{5\} = \{5\}$...

Comment: @user92570 Please see the comment under your question. I've linked a search (on this site) for the tags [tag:elementary-set-theory] and [tag:book-recommendation]. The only answered question for this search yields a good book it seems.

Answer (score 3):

No, a when $A \subseteq B$ then $A \subset B$ **or** $A = B$. Therefore, your first set is equal to $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\} \}$, while the second set is empty: $\{\}$ (there is no $x$ that fulfils the condition).